# Add click event on li on document load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Having list as ,

```
<ul id="test" >
  <li>list item 1</li>
  <li>list item 2</li>
  <li>list item 3</li>
  <li>list item 4</li>
  <li>list item 5</li>
</ul>
```

I want to apply click on specific li after document load. How can i do this using jquery ?

Comment: Any li or one of 3,4 ?

Comment: I'm not the downvoter... but the question is not at all clear... you want to register a click handler or trigger already registered click handlers

Comment: I guess the negative vote is because if you take time to read a bit the doc here http://api.jquery.com/click/ you'll find an answer

Comment: 9 answers is less than 5 minutes indicates that the answer is trivial.

Comment: Another question: Is this list created dynamically? Does the position of each li change? If yes, please add this to you question, because :eq(n) an :nth-child(n) aren't the best solution if the list changes.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to trigger `click` on first li then you can do:

```
$(window).on('load',function() {
    $('#test li:eq(0)').click();
});
```

Comment: isn't it better to use `.ready` to click on specific li after document load

Answer (score 1):

you can target a specific one using `nth-child()` so like:

```
$(function() {
    $("#test li:nth-child(n)").click(function(){
        //do you stuff
    });
});
```

Comment: I'm a little confused, isn't nth-child(n) going to search for a nth child of li? But you want to find the nth child of ul, right? so it has to be #test:nth-child(n), correct me please if im wrong.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $('#test li').click(function(){
         //your code goes here
     });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use jquery if you are familiar with it

```
$("#test").on("click", "li", function(){
   //custom code
});
```

Comment: From the jQuery-Documentation:
As of jQuery 1.7, the .on() method is the preferred method for attaching event handlers to a document.

Answer (score 0):

On spcecific **li**? You mena click on "item 3" but other items are not clickable?
Put an ID to the clickable item and asign the event as usualy.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function() {
  $('#test').on('click', 'li', function(event) {
    console.log(event.target);
  });
});
```

for more: http://jsfiddle.net/LvFYp/

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
nthli= $('#test li').find(':nth-child(n)');//replace n with index of li
 nthli.on('click', function() {
  //code here
});
```